# Full postback from UpdatePanel only if true

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, bootstrap-modal, updatepanel

I am trying to do a login system whereby if the user keys in a default password, it will prompt for a update of password.

The controls are all in an *UpdatePanel*, and i am able to force full postback from the control within the *UpdatePanel* by using for example at onLoad:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(btnClose)
```

However, i have another button which is *btnLogin*, and this will do the check if the password keyed in is the default. If it is not, then i will do a full postback. Below is my designer code:

```
<div id="aboutModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h3>Sign in with your username and password</h3>
                            <br/>
                            <p class="text-justify">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/> 
                                     <br />         
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  textmode="Password" />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPassword" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Update Password"  textmode="Password" Visible="false"/>
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Sign in" onclick="btnLogin_Click" /> 
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" class="btn btn-primary"  Visible ="true" OnClick="btnClose_Click"/>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                            </p>     
            <br/>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
 If dbPwd = "pwd123" Then

                    txtNewPassword.Visible = True
                    txtUsername.Text = username
                    txtPassword.Text = pwd


                Else

                    Dim signIn As Control = FindControl("signIn")
                    Dim logOut As Control = FindControl("logOut")

                    signIn.Visible = False
                    logOut.Visible = True

                    Session("loginDetails") = dbUsername & "," & dbGroup & "," & dbModify & "," & dbRead & "," & dbWrite
                    'MsgBox(Session("loginDetails"))
                    txtPassword.Text = ""
                    txtUsername.Text = ""
                    dbUsername = ""
                    dbPwd = ""

                    btnLogin.Visible = True

                End If
```

The question is how to conditionally register it as a control for full postback?

Comment: Why not `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(btnLogin)`?

Comment: hi @VDWWD, it works only if i put it in load. But at that point of time of login, only then i am able to determine if it is the default password. if it is the default password, txtNewPassword will then appear, else do a full postback.

Comment: You could place 2 login buttons in the UpdatePanel. One with postback and one without. And set their visibility, either in code behind or with javascript.

Comment: thank you @VDWWD for your suggestion. i guess that is the only way, i was thinking if there is a way for me to do a conditional postback by trigger.